# Exception thrown with SQLite result from Column with NULL value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

when selecting a column that can contains a NULL value I get an exception thrown on this statement.

```
self.DirectionFromCity = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 8)];
```

How should I go about setting these attributes as NULL values are OK for the Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per docs [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithUTF8String:) throws an exception if the bytes are null

What you need to do is check the returned value and only create the string if it is not null

```
char *localityChars = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 8);

if (localityChars == nil) {
     self.DirectionFromCity = nil;
} else {
     self.DirectionFromCity = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: localityChars];
}
```

In response to the comment below re code growing with the extra checking, you can shrink it down using

```
self.DirectionFromCity = localityChars != nil?[NSString stringWithUTF8String: localityChars]:nil;
```

or push it out to a method that will do the same functionality

```
self.DirectionFromCity = [self getSQLiteColumn:compiledStatement];
```

Comment: Thanks,

Ouch... I have 35 columns that can contain NULL this will add a lot of overhead to the app......

Comment: The overhead will be quite small, the only real difference is the 'if' block

Comment: Thanks Again,  I am concerned about both app performance and the size of the code neat solutions